# What is the technical reason behind why the FAA standard uses a 1000 ft aiming point and much larger runway numbers than the ICAO standard?

Tags: runways, faa, icao

[image: FAA standard]

[image: ICAO standard]

*FAA and ICAO standards, respectively.*

If the larger FAA runway numbers are for easier identification, why wouldn't ICAO also adopt  this feature to enhance safety?

Comment: Are the numbers really bigger? Your top (U.S.) image is zoomed in a lot more than the bottom (ICAO) image. This might account for some or all of the perceived size difference.

Comment: Yes, they are. The U.S. deviates from ICAO's Annex 14 with regard to the numbers.